# Why does my program keep raising EConvertError when using StrtoFloat() in Delphi 2007 for Win32?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007

My program takes a text file with 3 columns of data when prompted by the user by using file>open on the form. However, I only need the middle column of data from the textfile in order to plot a graph(using `TeeChart`). Therefore, the middle column from the textfile is stored in a string array

In order to plot the graph I need to use the `addXY()` function. Therefore I use a `for..do` loop to convert the the contents of the array of type string to of type float, which are then stored into a new array called display.

However, when I click a button (on the form) to display the graph, I keep getting

> "....raised exception class EConvertError with message "0.160 'is not a valid floating point value.'"

I've had a look through previous questions and tried to modify the `TFormatSettings` member `DecimalSeparator` to `'.'` and then pass `TFormatSettings` variable to `StrtoFloat()`. I'm not sure if I've implemented this correctly as it doesnt seem to work. I'd appreciate any help please.

I's relatively new to Delphi but have experience using C.

I've listed my program below:

```
var
 Form1     : TForm1;
 ft        : text;
 data      : Array[1..10000] of string;
 FS        : TFormatSettings;

implementation
{$R *.dfm}

{Open and store textfile}
procedure TForm1.Open_fileClick(Sender: TObject);
var
 col_1   : String[18];
 col_2   : String[7];
 col_3   : String[10];         //size of each column
 n       : smallint;

 begin
  if OpenDialog1.execute then
  n:=1;
  assignfile(ft,OpenDialog1.FileName);
  reset(ft);
  try
  while not Eof(ft) do
   begin
   Readln(ft, col_1, col_2,col_3);
   data[n]:= col_2;
   inc(n);
   end;

  Showmessage(data[3]); //check if correct value displayed

  finally
  CloseFile(ft);

end;
end;

{Display on TChart}
procedure TForm1.Display_dataClick(Sender: TObject);
var
 n: smallint;
 display : Array[1..10000] of single;
begin
 series1.clear;
 chart1.Title.Text.Clear;
 chart1.Title.Text.add('Output Data, y[n]');   //set up graph


 FillChar(FS, SizeOf(FS), 0);
 FS.DecimalSeparator := '.';      //is this correct?
 for n:=1 to 10000-1 do display[n]:= strtofloat(data[n+2],FS); 

 for n:=0 to 10000-1 do series1.addxy(n/10000,display[n]);
end;
end.
```

Comment: Might there be a space or other punctuation in the string?   The error message seems to indicate this.   If there is a space, try applying TRIM before StrToFloat.

Comment: Don't use `FillChar()` to initialize a `TFormatSettings` variable.  Use one of the static `TFormatSettings.Create()` methods instead, eg: `FS := TFormatSettings.Create;` The parameterless `Create()` initializes using settings from the default system locale. The other `Create()` overloads allow you to specify a specific locale by either ID or name.

Comment: ShowMessage(Data[3]) should be Data[n] presumably. You may have an error much later in the list. Are you sure that you have at least 1000 non-blank lines?

Comment: Big mistake to use long deprecated short strings. Use the native string type.

Comment: @Dsm Oh sorry I forgot to mention that the textfile is three columns of numbers with the first 2 rows as titles to the columns. That's why I wanted to see data[3], in order to test if it read the right number in the column. Yeah there is roughly 8000-10000 rows in the textfiles I want to read.

Comment: @DavidDubois Thanks for you help.  I tried using TRIM as the strings being stored in the array appeared something like this '0.167#9.' I think the #9 means tab? However, it still didn't work. I didn't realise I could just read/store them directly as reals from text file. So I just did that and it worked instead of storing as strings then converting.

Comment: @seerit #9 is the tab character, but that should be removed by TRIM if you applied it correctly (i.e. on the assignment to data[n]). But there is an obvious error. In the statement for n:=0 to 10000-1 do series1.addxy(n/10000,display[n]); display[0] does not exist!

Comment: I've rolled back your *Update* that provides the solution, because that's not how SO works. If you want to share the solution, use the space provided below and write an answer. Answering your own question is allowed here; there's information in the [help] that provides more details.

Answer (score 1):

You most likely have a stray carriage return or line feed in the parsed string data.  The easiest way to avoid this is to `Trim` your entries

```
data[n]:= Trim(col_2);
```

This removes any stray whitespace (including CR/LF).